# SAS: Exclude patients based on diagnoses on multiple lines and calculate incidence rates

Tags: sas, bioinformatics, frequency

I have large dataset of a few million patient encounters that include a diagnosis, timestamp, patientID, and demographic information.

For each patient, their diagnoses are listed on multiple lines. I need to exclude patients who have a certain diagnosis (282.1) and calculate incidence rates of other diseases in the year 2014.

```
IF diagnosis NE 282.1;
```

This in the data step does not work, because it does not take into account the other diagnoses on the other lines.

If possible, I would also like to calculate the incidence rates by disease.

This is an example of what the data looks like. There are multiple lines with multiple diagnoses.

```
PatientID   Diagnosis   Date    Gender  Age
1           282.1       1/2/10      F   25
1           232.1       1/2/10      F   87
1           250.02      1/2/10      F   41
1           125.1       1/2/10      F   46
1           90.1        1/2/10      F   58
2           140         12/15/13    M   57
2           132.3       12/15/13    M   41
2           149.1       12/15/13    M   66
3           601.1       11/19/13    F   58
3           231.1       11/19/13    F   76
3           123.1       11/19/13    F   29
4           282.1       12/30/14    F   81
4           130.1       12/30/14    F   86
5           230.1       1/22/14     M   60
5           282.1       1/22/14     M   46
5           250.02      1/22/14     M   53
```

Comment: Do you need incidence rates of just a few diseases, different from 282.1, or a lot?

Comment: @DirkHorsten I need incidence rates for a lot of diseases, different from 282.1

Comment: What incidences do you need: __visits/treatments per Diagnose and PatientID__ or __visits/treatments per Diagnose__ or __distinct PatientID's per Diagnose__ ? Probably you could add a snipped of how you would like the result to look like.

Comment: @DirkHorsten The incidences I need are distinct PatientIDs per diagnosis in a given year. For example, I would like to make a table with rows of diseases and their incidences.

Comment: If someone gets diagnose 282.1 in 2013, do you need to exclude his/her diagnoses for other diseases for 2011? And for 2015?

Comment: @DickHorsten that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dual reading sollution

### Straight forward version

You said you sorted the data first, probably like this

```
proc sort data=MYLIB.DIAGNOSES;
    by PatientID;
run;
```

Assuming your data is ordered by `patientID`, you can process each with the diagnose to exclude first.

```
data WORK.NOT_HAVING_282_1;
    set MYLIB.DIAGNOSES (where=(diagnosis EQ 282.1)) 
        MYLIB.DIAGNOSES (where=(diagnosis NE 282.1));
    by PatientID;
```

As we need to report by year, not by date:

```
year = year(Date);
```

Next step is to exclude those you don't need, so you need to remember if the unwanted diagnose occured:

```
    retain has_282_1;
    if first.PatientID then has_282_1 = 0;
    if diagnosis EQ 282.1 then has_282_1 = 1;
```

and then keep the other diagnoses in 2014 for patients that do not have 282.1

```
    else if not has_282_1 then output;
run;
```

Next you could SQL to count what you need

```
proc sql:
    create table MYLIB.STATISTICS as 
    select year, Diagonsis, count(distinct PatientID) as incidence
    from WORK.NOT_HAVING_282_1
    group by year, Diagonsis;
quit;
```

### Improvements

The above solution would take more processing power then needed:

- you read `DIAGNOSES` from diks, then write FIRST_282_1 to disk, just to read it back in again
- you can keep multiple observations of the same diagnose at diffrerent dates in the same year for the same patient, so you need `count(distinct PatientID)`, which is a costly operation.

About diagnose 282.1, we only need to know who was ever diagnosed:

```
proc sort noduplicates
    data=MYLIB.DIAGNOSES (where=(diagnosis EQ 282.1))
    out=WORK.HAVING_282_1 (keep=PatientID);
    by PatientID;
run;
```

About other diagnoses, we also need the year, which here:

```
data WORK.VIEW_OTHER / view=WORK.VIEW_OTHER;
    set MYLIB.DIAGNOSES (where=(diagnosis NE 282.1));
    year = year(Date);
    keep PatientID year Diagnose;
run;
```

but as we use a view, we do not realy read and calculate anything before the view is used in this sort:

```
proc sort noduplicates
    data=WORK.VIEW_OTHER (where=(diagnosis EQ 282.1))
    out=WORK.OTHER_DIAGNOSES;

    by PatientID year Diagnose;
run;
```

Now things become simpler. We use temproary variables `exclude` and `other` to indicate where data came from

```
data WORK.NOT_HAVING_282_1;
    set WORK.HAVING_282_1 (in=exclude)
        WORK.OTHER_DIAGNOSES (in=other);
    by PatientID;

    retain has_282_1;
    if first.PatientID then has_282_1 = exclude;

    if other and not has_282_1 then output;
run;

proc sql:
    create table MYLIB.STATISTICS as 
    select year, Diagonsis, count(*) as incidence
    from WORK.NOT_HAVING_282_1
    group by year, Diagonsis;
quit;
```

*Remark: this code is not tested*

Comment: @DickHorsten if the data is not ordered by patientID, will this still work?

Comment: __No__, like it is written above, will only work if the data is sorted. __Is your data sorted__ by `PatientID`? If not, __are observations grouped by patient__, or are data from different patients __intermingled__? _And in what format do you have the data: a sas dataset, a text file or a database?_

Comment: The data from different patients are intermingled, but I did PROC SORT; by PatientID. The data is in .sas7bdat format